# cordova j3k0 / cordova-plugin-purchase fails on iOS 13 for my ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, ionic4, cordova-plugins

I have several existing apps on App Store and I was trying to add the another one but my app keeps getting rejected by Apple due to inapp purchase issues. I have not changed the inapp purchase code so I am not sure what could possibly be wrong. I do not have a mac as I build things on the cloud; hence, wanted to reach out to the community for guidance. Please find what I observed below:

1. I am aware that you cannot test inapp purchase on the simulator. However, the simulator can display the store data fine. In other words, the inapp should be set OK on the itunes side.
2. On iOS 11, the purchase brings a pop up for user to log in. However, on iOS 13 it fails directly by `"Cannot connect to the itunes store"` message. Hence, I assume the issue could be related to iOS13 or something I should have done to handle iOS 13.
   Apple tests my app on iOS13 and my prior apps were approved in the past, possibly on iOS11. Moreover, the rejection by apple also indicated the same error message.
3. On iOS13, I also see the following error at the logs:

```
Found nil parameter when creating SKPaymentDiscount
```

Below is the basic structure of my code:

At the app initialization I called the following method:

```
  configurePurchasing() {
      try {                          
          this.iapStore.register({
              id: this.productId,
              alias: this.productAlias,
              type: this.iapStore.CONSUMABLE
          });
              
          this.iapStore.when(productId).approved((product) => {
              product.finish();
              
              // Purchase is completed         
          });           

          this.iapStore.when(productId).updated((product) => {
              this.renderProductInfo();                    
          });

          this.iapStore.when(productId).cancelled((product) => {
              // Show purchase cancelled message   
          });
             
          this.iapStore.error((err) => {
              // Show error message
          });

          this.iapStore.ready((status) => {                    
              this.renderProductInfo();                    
          });

          this.iapStore.when(productId).error((err) => {
              // Show error message
          });                
          
          this.iapStore.refresh();            
      }
      catch (err) {
      }
  }

  renderProductInfo() {
    try {                  
        let product = this.iapStore.get(this.productId);        

        if (!product) {                    
          // Show error message       
        }
        else if (product.state === this.iapStore.INVALID) {
          // Show error message             
        }                
        else if (product.state === this.iapStore.VALID) {
            // Product loaded and valid.
            if (this.storeInfoLoadedFlag == false) {              
              this.title = product.title;
              this.price = product.price;
              this.description = product.description;                             
            }
            else if (this.purchaseErrorFlag) {
          // Show error message       
            }
            else if (this.purchaseCancelledFlag) {                        
          // Show cancel message
            }                         
        }                            
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
  }
```

And below is my purchase method:

```
  purchaseLives() {
      try {                        
          productId = this.productId;
          this.iapStore.get(productId);              
          this.iapStore.order(productId);
          
      }
      catch (err) {
      }
  }
```

I would be immensely grateful if you could provide any pointer as I do not have a mac to test the code on a real device.

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: did you also create the issue on the plugin's developer github?

Comment: Hi Sergey, many thanks for your response. Yes, I have created an issue there but I am concerned that I miss something obvious rather than an issue with the plugin. Hence, I created a question here as it might be more of a coding issue on my end with respect to iOS 13.